# Pygame - permantly adjusting master volume

Tags: python, audio, numpy, pygame, volume

I have a program that plays a sine wave note on keypress. the idea is to simulate an instrument. I have some code added for adjusting volume, but this value for the volume seems to be refreshed every time a new note is played. How can this be adjusted so that when a key is pressed to adjust the volume, the volume remains at this value until changed again?

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

import math
import numpy

pygame.init()
bits = 16

pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, -bits, 2)

def generate_sound(freq):
    volume = 0.5

    for i in range(pygame.mixer.get_num_channels()):
                c = pygame.mixer.Channel(i)
            c.set_volume(volume)

        for s in range(n_samples):
            t = float(s)/sample_rate    # time in seconds
            buf[s][0] = int(round(max_sample*math.sin(2*math.pi*freq*t)))    # left
            buf[s][1] = int(round(max_sample*math.sin(2*math.pi*freq*t)))    # right

        return pygame.sndarray.make_sound(buf)

size = (1200, 720)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size, pygame.HWSURFACE | pygame.DOUBLEBUF)


duration = 2.0          # in seconds

sample_rate = 44100

n_samples = int(round(duration*sample_rate))

#lower
sound_130_81 = generate_sound(130.81)   #C

_running = True
while _running:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            _running = False


        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            #Volume control
            if event.key == K_1:
                for i in range(pygame.mixer.get_num_channels()):
                    c = pygame.mixer.Channel(i)
                c.set_volume(0.1)

            elif event.key == K_2:
                for i in range(pygame.mixer.get_num_channels()):
                    c = pygame.mixer.Channel(i)
                c.set_volume(0.2)

            elif event.key == K_3:
                for i in range(pygame.mixer.get_num_channels()):
                    c = pygame.mixer.Channel(i)
                c.set_volume(0.3)

            elif event.key == K_4:
                for i in range(pygame.mixer.get_num_channels()):
                    c = pygame.mixer.Channel(i)
                c.set_volume(0.4)

            elif event.key == K_5:
                for i in range(pygame.mixer.get_num_channels()):
                    c = pygame.mixer.Channel(i)
                c.set_volume(0.5)

            elif event.key == K_6:
                for i in range(pygame.mixer.get_num_channels()):
                    c = pygame.mixer.Channel(i)
                c.set_volume(0.6)

            elif event.key == K_7:
                for i in range(pygame.mixer.get_num_channels()):
                    c = pygame.mixer.Channel(i)
                c.set_volume(0.7)

            elif event.key == K_8:
                for i in range(pygame.mixer.get_num_channels()):
                    c = pygame.mixer.Channel(i)
                c.set_volume(0.8)

            elif event.key == K_9:
                for i in range(pygame.mixer.get_num_channels()):
                    c = pygame.mixer.Channel(i)
                c.set_volume(0.9)

            elif event.key == K_0:
                for i in range(pygame.mixer.get_num_channels()):
                    c = pygame.mixer.Channel(i)
                c.set_volume(1.0)

            elif event.key == K_BACKSPACE:
                for i in range(pygame.mixer.get_num_channels()):
                    c = pygame.mixer.Channel(i)
                c.set_volume(0.0)

                volume = c.get_volume()

            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                _running = False

            #lower notes DOWN

            elif event.key == K_z:
                sound_130_81.play(-1)


        if event.type == KEYUP:

            #lower notes UP

            if event.key == K_z:
                sound_130_81.fadeout(350) #fade sound by .35 seconds

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: It would really help to remove all the extraneous code and give up a stripped-down example, just enough to demonstrate the problem. See [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for further details.

Comment: I'm not certain how much would be relevant, because the relevant parts are all throughout the code, not just one section

Comment: Please follow the link to MCVE, it explains it better than I can in a short comment. But you can strip it down to just the relevant parts, even if they're all throughout the code, and just enough scaffolding to connect them up. For example, clearly you don't need a couple dozen calls to `generate_sound`, dozens of key handlers, etc. to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the volume at the start of your generate_sound method.  You need to use the existing value for it rather than setting it to a fixed value every time.  Either pass it in as a parameter that can be adjusted in the caller (preferable) or set it as a global value if supported by your language.

I don't know python specifically, but it would probably work as something like the following:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

import math
import numpy

pygame.init()
bits = 16
volume = 0.5

pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, -bits, 2)

def generate_sound(freq, volume):

    for i in range(pygame.mixer.get_num_channels()):
                c = pygame.mixer.Channel(i)
            c.set_volume(volume)

        #setup our numpy array to handle 16 bit ints, which is what we set our mixer to expect with "bits" up above
        buf = numpy.zeros((n_samples, 2), dtype = numpy.int16)
        max_sample = 2**(bits - 1) - 1

        for s in range(n_samples):
            t = float(s)/sample_rate    # time in seconds
            buf[s][0] = int(round(max_sample*math.sin(2*math.pi*freq*t)))    # left
            buf[s][1] = int(round(max_sample*math.sin(2*math.pi*freq*t)))    # right

        return pygame.sndarray.make_sound(buf)

size = (1200, 720)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size, pygame.HWSURFACE | pygame.DOUBLEBUF)


duration = 2.0          # in seconds

sample_rate = 44100

n_samples = int(round(duration*sample_rate))


#lower
sound_130_81 = generate_sound(130.81, volume)   #C
sound_146_83 = generate_sound(146.83, volume)   #D
sound_164_81 = generate_sound(164.81, volume)   #E
sound_174_61 = generate_sound(174.61, volume)   #F
sound_196_00 = generate_sound(196.00, volume)   #G
sound_220_00 = generate_sound(220.00, volume)   #A
sound_246_94 = generate_sound(246.94, volume)   #B
#middle
sound_261_63 = generate_sound(261.63, volume)   #C
sound_293_66 = generate_sound(293.66, volume)   #D
sound_329_63 = generate_sound(329.63, volume)   #E
sound_349_23 = generate_sound(349.23, volume)   #F
sound_392_00 = generate_sound(392.00, volume)   #G
sound_440_00 = generate_sound(440.00, volume)   #A
sound_493_88 = generate_sound(493.88, volume)   #B
#higher
sound_523_25 = generate_sound(523.25, volume)   #C
sound_587_33 = generate_sound(587.33, volume)   #D
sound_659_25 = generate_sound(659.25, volume)   #E
sound_698_46 = generate_sound(698.46, volume)   #F
sound_783_99 = generate_sound(783.99, volume)   #G
sound_880_00 = generate_sound(880.00, volume)   #A
sound_987_77 = generate_sound(987.77, volume)   #B
sound_1046_50 = generate_sound(1046.50, volume) #C

#This will keep the sound playing forever, the quit event handling allows the pygame window to close without crashing
_running = True
while _running:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            _running = False


        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            #Volume control
            if event.key == K_1:
                for i in range(pygame.mixer.get_num_channels()):
                    c = pygame.mixer.Channel(i)
                c.set_volume(0.1)

            elif event.key == K_2:
                for i in range(pygame.mixer.get_num_channels()):
                    c = pygame.mixer.Channel(i)
                c.set_volume(0.2)

            elif event.key == K_3:
                for i in range(pygame.mixer.get_num_channels()):
                    c = pygame.mixer.Channel(i)
                c.set_volume(0.3)

            elif event.key == K_4:
                for i in range(pygame.mixer.get_num_channels()):
                    c = pygame.mixer.Channel(i)
                c.set_volume(0.4)

            elif event.key == K_5:
                for i in range(pygame.mixer.get_num_channels()):
                    c = pygame.mixer.Channel(i)
                c.set_volume(0.5)

            elif event.key == K_6:
                for i in range(pygame.mixer.get_num_channels()):
                    c = pygame.mixer.Channel(i)
                c.set_volume(0.6)

            elif event.key == K_7:
                for i in range(pygame.mixer.get_num_channels()):
                    c = pygame.mixer.Channel(i)
                c.set_volume(0.7)

            elif event.key == K_8:
                for i in range(pygame.mixer.get_num_channels()):
                    c = pygame.mixer.Channel(i)
                c.set_volume(0.8)

            elif event.key == K_9:
                for i in range(pygame.mixer.get_num_channels()):
                    c = pygame.mixer.Channel(i)
                c.set_volume(0.9)

            elif event.key == K_0:
                for i in range(pygame.mixer.get_num_channels()):
                    c = pygame.mixer.Channel(i)
                c.set_volume(1.0)

            elif event.key == K_BACKSPACE:
                for i in range(pygame.mixer.get_num_channels()):
                    c = pygame.mixer.Channel(i)
                c.set_volume(0.0)

                volume = c.get_volume()

            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                _running = False

            #lower notes DOWN

            elif event.key == K_z:
                sound_130_81.play(-1)

            elif event.key == K_x:
                sound_146_83.play(-1)

            elif event.key == K_c:
                sound_164_81.play(-1)

            elif event.key == K_v:
                sound_174_61.play(-1)

            elif event.key == K_b:
                sound_196_00.play(-1)

            elif event.key == K_n:
                sound_220_00.play(-1)

            elif event.key == K_m:
                sound_246_94.play(-1)

            elif event.key == K_COMMA:
                sound_261_63.play(-1) 


            #middle notes DOWN

            elif event.key == K_a:
                sound_261_63.play(-1)

            elif event.key == K_s:
                sound_293_66.play(-1)

            elif event.key == K_d:
                sound_329_63.play(-1)

            elif event.key == K_f:
                sound_349_23.play(-1)

            elif event.key == K_g:
                sound_392_00.play(-1)

            elif event.key == K_h:
                sound_440_00.play(-1)

            elif event.key == K_j:
                sound_493_88.play(-1)

            elif event.key == K_k:
                sound_523_25.play(-1)


            #higher notes DOWN

            elif event.key == K_q:
                sound_523_25.play(-1)

            elif event.key == K_w:
                sound_587_33.play(-1)

            elif event.key == K_e:
                sound_659_25.play(-1)

            elif event.key == K_r:
                sound_698_46.play(-1)

            elif event.key == K_t:
                sound_783_99.play(-1)

            elif event.key == K_y:
                sound_880_00.play(-1)

            elif event.key == K_u:
                sound_987_77.play(-1)

            elif event.key == K_i:
                sound_1046_50.play(-1)

        if event.type == KEYUP:

            #lower notes UP

            if event.key == K_z:
                sound_130_81.fadeout(350) #fade sound by .35 seconds

            elif event.key == K_x:
                sound_146_83.fadeout(1000)

            elif event.key == K_c:
                sound_164_81.fadeout(350)

            elif event.key == K_v:
                sound_174_61.fadeout(350)

            elif event.key == K_b:
                sound_196_00.fadeout(350)

            elif event.key == K_n:
                sound_220_00.fadeout(350)

            elif event.key == K_m:
                sound_246_94.fadeout(350)

            elif event.key == K_COMMA:
                sound_261_63.fadeout(350)

            #middle notes UP

            elif event.key == K_a:
                sound_261_63.fadeout(350)

            elif event.key == K_s:
                sound_293_66.fadeout(350)

            elif event.key == K_d:
                sound_329_63.fadeout(350)

            elif event.key == K_f:
                sound_349_23.fadeout(350)

            elif event.key == K_g:
                sound_392_00.fadeout(350)

            elif event.key == K_h:
                sound_440_00.fadeout(350)

            elif event.key == K_j:
                sound_493_88.fadeout(350)

            elif event.key == K_k:
                sound_523_25.fadeout(350)

            #higher notes UP

            elif event.key == K_q:
                sound_523_25.fadeout(350)

            elif event.key == K_w:
                sound_587_33.fadeout(350)

            elif event.key == K_e:
                sound_659_25.fadeout(350)

            elif event.key == K_r:
                sound_698_46.fadeout(350)

            elif event.key == K_t:
                sound_783_99.fadeout(350)

            elif event.key == K_y:
                sound_880_00.fadeout(350)

            elif event.key == K_u:
                sound_987_77.fadeout(350)

            elif event.key == K_i:
                sound_1046_50.fadeout(350)

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: I have tried this, but I can't see a way to make this work, anything I try ends up with volume being undefined. Can you possibly provide an example from my code?

Comment: I can give it a guess, but I don't know python, nor do I have a python development environment.

Comment: @user3856722: Instead of saying "anything I try ends up with volume being undefined", show us what you tried, and exactly what happened and where (a full traceback, if what happened was an exception).

Comment: I can't go over everything I have tried, because I did many variations of it, I basically used the code above, with the volume variable defined in different places, but trying, for example, setting volume to the value of the current volume created by the keypress, gives no different result to not doing this anyway...

Comment: @user3856722: The code shown in this answer is not going to "end up with volume being undefined" (by which I assume you mean a `NameError`?), so if that's what you're seeing, clearly you didn't actually run this code. We can't help you debug code that we can't see.